# Asterisk JITTERBUFFER function details

Tags: asterisk, voip, jitter

Asterisk v15 documentation states that JITTERBUFFER function is used to "add a Jitterbuffer to the Read side of the channel". Take this dialplan example:

```
[from-pstn]
exten => 1234,1,Set(JITTERBUFFER(adaptive)=default)
exten => 1234,n,Dial(PJSIP/1234)
```

It is safe to assume that jitter buffer is applied to the calling channel. What about the answering channel (PJSIP/1234 in this case)? Is jitter buffer applied to it as well? If not, how to apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer on Asterisk community forums. Jitter buffer is not applied to outbound channel, it needs to be set in predial handler. For example:

```
exten => outbound_jitterbuf,1,NoOp()
same => n,Set(JITTERBUFFER(adaptive)=default)
same => n,Return()

exten => alice,1,Noop()
same => n,Dial(${TECH}/${EXTEN},20,b(default^outbound_jitterbuf^1))
```